# PowerBuilder 10.5 with MS Office 2010

Tags: automation, ms-office, powerbuilder

We are using MS Office 2010 with PowerBuilder 10.5. While using mail merge functionality from PowerBuilder application. It got application terminated. But in the later version works as usual..

I checked the Word document in the older version.. When opening that word document ( mail merge used in that) the data file (recipient file of address_data.xls) also will be opening. But in the Newer version it didn't open. is there any option to open the excel file, while opening the document?

When opening the mail merged word document. It opens with Excel file in MS Office 97. But this is not working in MS Office 2010. I need to open that document in MS Office 2010 - Word 2010 so this should open that excel file too. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi, can you please clarify? What were you using that worked? What did you change? Please post the PowerBuilder code you are using to control Word.

Comment: ole_1.object.application.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Execute() This is the line - here the application terminated.

Comment: When opening the mail merged word document. It opens with Excel file in MS Office 97. But this is not working in MS Office 2010. I need to open that document in MS Office 2010 - Word 2010 so this should open that excel file too. How can I do that?

Comment: What happens when you open the document from Word (not using PB)? If the mail merge won't work in Word it won't work in PB. You might have to make a new Word document for Office 2010.

Comment: While opening the work document, it asked conversion from the existing version. i said yes then opens word document with the excel document. This is the desired behaviour but the code  
ole_1.Object.Application.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Execute() this part fails and returns the powerbuilder application error(R0035)

Comment: In MicroSoft - MS Office 2010 support they provided one solution for this type of issue which i was mentioned earlier in this. While opening the mail merge document with excel.. its checking the SQLSecuritycheck so we need to add a property to block the check on registry for the word option. it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening the Word document like this:

```
iole_word = CREATE OLEObject
li_result  = iole_word.ConnectToNewObject("word.application")
// error checking code omitted

// args: FileName, [ConfirmConversions], [ReadOnly], [AddToRecentFiles]
ole_1 = iole_word.Documents.Open(is_infile,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)
```

I didn't show it here, but you should put the whole thing in a try-catch block and catch `oleruntimeerror`. If Word can't open the file, it throws `oleruntimeerror`. I presume that's also what it's throwing when the `MailMerge` fails.

If that doesn't work I'd make a new mailmerge document for Office 2010. If you need to support both versions you could check the Word version via the OLE interface to determine which document to use.

Comment: Thanks for writing me, we have option in Word 2010. The option we need to check. the option is "Confirm file format convertion on open". It opens the correct datasources file, when opeing the word document.

Comment: We have a problem in MS Office 2010. when using the mailmerge functionality with PowerBuilder 10.5 we will face the PowerBuilder application Runtime error (R0039). and also application will terminate by calling external object function execute at line xx on ABCD. The MS Office 2010 has a solution for that, it needs to be added in Registry entry that is SQLSecurityCheck-REG-DWORD (32-Bit) - value = 0 on 14.0. after adding the property in registry entry. its working.